# Q: JPA save() save other object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I want to know the detail of JAP Repotitoty.
I created a service class, eintity classes and repository classes like as below(written in kotlin) and excecuted ItemService#update method.

Both item1 and item2 were updated when item2Repository's save() method was executed.

```
@Service
class ItemService(@Autowired private val item1Repository: Item1Repository, @Autowired private val item2Repository: Item2Repository) {

    fun update(id: Long) {

        val item1 = item1Repository.findById(1).get()
        item1.name = "updated!"

        val item2 = item2Repository.findById(1).get()
        item2.name = "updated!"

        // item1 and item2 were updated.
        item2Repository.save(item2)
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "item1")
data class Item1(

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long = 0,

        @Column
        var name: String = ""
)    

@Entity
@Table(name = "item2")
data class Item2(

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long = 0,

        @Column
        var name: String = ""
)

interface Item1Repository: JpaRepository<Item1, Long>

interface Item2Repository: JpaRepository<Item2, Long>
```

Why was item1 updated?
I think that both item1 and item2 are managed in persistence context when findById methods are executed. 
Will be all objects existing in persistence context saved when I execute save method of a jpa repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is "managed" instance, you don't have to call `save` to save it - all changes made to the managed instance will be reflected in the database.
In order to prevent that behavior, your would have to detach that instance making it act like POJO insteed of proxy.

Save is used to either `persist` new entities or `merge` detached.